IceCandidate is not being sent in webrtc client in Kotlin
IceCandidate is not being sent and IceCandidateState is not even being gathered. SdpOffer is being sent and received.
My code is below
Signalling Client
class SignallingClient @Inject constructor(
    private val socket: Socket,
    private val peerConnectionFactory: PeerConnectionFactory,
    private val rtcConfig: PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration
) {
    private lateinit var userId: String
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SignallingClient"
    }

    val peerConnection =
        peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, object : PeerConnectionAdapter(TAG) {
            override fun onIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
                super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
                addIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
                Log.d(TAG, "Ice candidate generated: ${iceCandidate.sdp}")
                sendIceCandidateToSignallingServer(
                    candidate = iceCandidate,
                    userId = userId,
                    roomId = "room1",
                    user = WebRtcUser(
                        id = userId,
                        role = "host",
                        name = "Gursimar Singh"
                    )
                )
            }

            override fun onIceGatheringChange(iceGatheringState: PeerConnection.IceGatheringState) {
                super.onIceGatheringChange(iceGatheringState)
                Log.d(TAG, "Ice gathering state changed to: $iceGatheringState")
                when (iceGatheringState) {
                    PeerConnection.IceGatheringState.NEW -> Log.d(TAG, "ICE Gathering started")
                    PeerConnection.IceGatheringState.GATHERING -> Log.d(TAG, "ICE Candidate gathering in progress")
                    PeerConnection.IceGatheringState.COMPLETE -> Log.d(TAG, "ICE Candidate gathering complete")
                }
            }

        })

    init {
        connect()
    }

    private fun addIceCandidate(candidate: IceCandidate) {
        peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(candidate)
    }

    private fun connect() {
        socket.connect()
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            Log.d("Socket", "Connected to Socket.IO")
        }
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {
            Log.e("Socket", "Connection error: ${it.joinToString()}")
        }
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        socket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            Log.d("Socket", "Disconnected from Socket.IO")
        }
        socket.disconnect()
    }

    suspend fun init() {
        val userId = getUserIdFromSocket()
        sendOfferToSignallingServer(
            user = WebRtcUser(
                id = userId,
                role = "host",
                name = "Gursimar Singh"
            ),
            roomId = "room1"
        )
        receiveOfferFromSignallingServer()
    }

    private suspend fun getUserIdFromSocket(): String {
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
            socket.on("connection") { args ->
                if (args.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val data = args[0] as JSONObject
                    Log.d(TAG, data.toString())
                    userId = data.getString("userID")
                    Log.d(TAG, "User ID: $userId")
                    continuation.resume(userId)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No data received")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun sendOfferToSignallingServer(user: WebRtcUser, roomId: String) {
        val constraints = MediaConstraints().apply {
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("audio", "true"))
            optional.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", "320"))
            optional.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", "15"))
            optional.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", "15"))
        }
        user.rtcPeer = peerConnection
        peerConnection?.createOffer(object : SdpAdapter(TAG) {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(object : SdpAdapter(TAG) {
                    override fun onSetSuccess() {
                        offerMessageToSignallingServer(user, sessionDescription.description, roomId)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Offer sent: ${sessionDescription.description}")
                    }
                }, sessionDescription)
            }
        }, constraints)
    }

    private fun offerMessageToSignallingServer(user: WebRtcUser, offer: String, roomId: String) {
        if (user.role == "stream") {
//             Assuming you have a socket for stream connection
            socket.emit(
                "signalling", mapOf(
                    "action" to "sdpOffer",
                    "offer" to offer,
                    "offerFor" to user.id
                )
            )
        } else {
            when (user.role) {
                "host" -> {
                    val host = JSONObject().apply {
                        put("action", "start")
                        put("roomName", roomId)
                        put("role", "host")
                        put("userName", user.name)
                    }
                    socket.emit("host", host)
                }

                "member" -> {
                    val start = JSONObject().apply {
                        put("action", "start")
                        put("roomName", roomId)
                        put("role", "member")
                    }
                    socket.emit("member", start)
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending offer to ${user.id}")
            // Assuming you have a standard socket connection
            val sendOffer = JSONObject().apply {
                put("action", "sdpOffer")
                put("offerFor", user.id)
                put("roomID", roomId)
                put("offer", offer)
                put("role", user.role)
            }
            socket.emit("signalling", sendOffer)
        }
    }

    private fun receiveOfferFromSignallingServer() {
        socket.on("signalling") { args ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Signalling message received")
            if (args.isNotEmpty()) {
                val message = args[0] as JSONObject
                when (message.getString("action")) {
                    "sdpAnswer" -> {
                        val senderID = message.getString("senderID")
                        val sdpAnswer = message.getString("sdpAnswer")
                        Log.d(TAG, "Answer received: $sdpAnswer")
                        processAnswer(senderID, sdpAnswer)
                    }

                    "candidate" -> {
                        val userID = message.getString("userID")
                        val candidate = message.getString("candidate")
                        Log.d(TAG, "Candidate received: $userID, $candidate")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun processAnswer(senderID: String, sdpAnswer: String) {
        if (peerConnection?.signalingState() == PeerConnection.SignalingState.HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER) {
            val sessionDescription = SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER, sdpAnswer)
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(object : SdpAdapter(TAG) {
                override fun onSetSuccess() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Remote description set successfully for $senderID")
                }
            }, sessionDescription)
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "PeerConnection is in an invalid state: ${peerConnection?.signalingState()}")
        }
    }

    fun sendIceCandidateToSignallingServer(
        candidate: IceCandidate,
        userId: String,
        roomId: String,
        user: WebRtcUser
    ) {
        if (user.role == "stream") {
            val streamJson = JSONObject().apply {
                put("action", "candidate")
                put("candidate", candidate.sdp)
                put("role", "steam")
                put("roomId", roomId)
            }
            socket.emit("signalling", streamJson)
        } else {
            val candidateJson = JSONObject().apply {
                put("action", "candidate")
                put("for", userId)
                put("roomName", roomId)
                put("role", user.role)
                put("candidate", candidate.sdp)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, candidateJson.toString())
            socket.emit("signalling", candidateJson)
        }
    }
}

PeerConnectionAdapter
open class PeerConnectionAdapter(tag: String) : Observer {
    private val tag: String = "chao $tag"
    private fun log(s: String) {
        Log.d(tag, s)
    }

    override fun onSignalingChange(signalingState: SignalingState) {
        log("onSignalingChange $signalingState")
    }

    override fun onIceConnectionChange(iceConnectionState: IceConnectionState) {
        log("onIceConnectionChange $iceConnectionState")
    }

    override fun onIceConnectionReceivingChange(b: Boolean) {
        log("onIceConnectionReceivingChange $b")
    }

    override fun onIceGatheringChange(iceGatheringState: IceGatheringState) {
        log("onIceGatheringChange $iceGatheringState")
    }

    override fun onIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
        log("onIceCandidate $iceCandidate")

    }

    override fun onIceCandidatesRemoved(iceCandidates: Array<IceCandidate>) {
        log("onIceCandidatesRemoved $iceCandidates")
    }

    override fun onAddStream(mediaStream: MediaStream) {
        log("onAddStream $mediaStream")
    }

    override fun onRemoveStream(mediaStream: MediaStream) {
        log("onRemoveStream $mediaStream")
    }

    override fun onDataChannel(dataChannel: DataChannel) {
        log("onDataChannel $dataChannel")
    }

    override fun onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        log("onRenegotiationNeeded ")
    }

    override fun onAddTrack(rtpReceiver: RtpReceiver, mediaStreams: Array<MediaStream>) {
        log("onAddTrack $mediaStreams")
    }

    override fun onConnectionChange(newState: PeerConnectionState?) {
        log("onConnectionChange $newState")
    }
}


I am able to generate offer and receive offer but unable to send IceCandidate. I am not even receing logs of onIceCandidateChange
